# What is making my code use so much memory?

Tags: java, performance, scala, memory

I have solved in various ways a simple problem on CodeEval, which specification can be found [here](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/124/) (only a few lines long).

I have made 3 working versions (one of them in Scala) and I don't understand the difference of performances for my last Java version which I expected to be the best time and memory-wise.

I also compared this to a code found on [Github](https://github.com/mpillar/codeeval/blob/master/0-easy/road-trip/Main.java). Here are the performance stats returned by CodeEval :

[image: Stats]

. Version 1 is the version found on Github
. Version 2 is my Scala solution :

```
object Main extends App {
    val p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines
        .filter(!_.isEmpty)
        .map(line => {
            val dists = new TreeSet[Int]
            val m     = p.matcher(line)
            while (m.find) dists += m.group.toInt

            val list  = dists.toList
            list.zip(0 +: list).map { case (x,y) => x - y }.mkString(",")
        })
        .foreach(println)
}
```

. Version 3 is my Java solution which I expected to be the best :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Pattern        p    = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        File           file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader br   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Set<Integer> dists = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            Matcher      m     = p.matcher(line); 
            while (m.find()) dists.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));

            Iterator<Integer> it   = dists.iterator();
            int               prev = 0;
            StringBuilder     sb   = new StringBuilder();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int curr = it.next();
                sb.append(curr - prev);
                sb.append(it.hasNext() ? "," : "");
                prev = curr;
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

- Version 4 is the same as version 3 except I don't use a `StringBuilder` to print the output and do like in version 1

Here is how I interpreted those results :

- version 1 is too slow because of the too high number of `System.out.print` calls. Moreover, using `split` on very large lines (that's the case in the tests performed) uses a lot of memory.
- version 2 seems slow too but it is mainly because of an "overhead" on running Scala code on CodeEval, even very efficient code run slowly on it
- version 2 uses unnecessary memory to build a list from the set, which also takes some time but should not be too significant. Writing more efficient Scala would probably like writing it in Java so I preferred elegance to performance
- version 3 should not use that much memory in my opinion. The use of a `StringBuilder` has the same impact on memory as calling `mkString` in version 2
- version 4 proves the calls to `System.out.println` are slowering down the program

Does someone see an explanation to those results ?

Comment: This type of question might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm starting to think that CodeEval stats might not be reliable...

Comment: Maybe 5M (Java) was before GC occurs, but 1.7M (Scala) after...

Comment: Actually I don't really know how they determine those stats. The input file size varies a bit but stays roughly 250Ko and the total size of my input (I wrote in a file instead of printing on the standard output) is 56Ko, so I wonder how I could use more than 5 Mo...

Comment: Note that in version 3 you are creating a new StringBuilder every time. The default constructor gets an internal buffer of length 16 only. If you have long strings to build, you'd better to re-use a single StirngBuilder rather than recreating it every time. That's can takes a lot of memory before JVM issues GC. You can do StringBuilder.setLength(0) to clear the buffer and reuse it. You recreate a Set<Integer> for every line, too.

Comment: @AlexSuo note that the same goes for the Scala code. I took your remarks into account and got a little speed-up (1155 ms instead of 1291 ms) but the memory usage was equivalent. Thanks for the remark though, as it improved the running time

Comment: You could move the creation of the `TreeSet` and the `StringBuilder` out of the loop and just call `clear`/`setLength(0)` on them for each line. It then must be `line` that is eating your memory.

Comment: @Dici Are you sure Scala is using the same Pattern.compile underlying? Because if you look at that piece of code it generates a lot of rubbish in memory.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon yes, I moved it following AlexSuo message. The lines are indeed very long, but reading a line at a time is the minimum I can do in any version. I will try using different types of readers thoight.

Comment: @AlexSuo yes it is the same as I imported `Pattern` from `java.util` in the Scala code. Why does it generate rubbish ?

Comment: @Dici You can trace in the JDK source code. It creates a lot of int[] and object arrays etc for each matcher() call.

Comment: Why guess?  Use a profiler, or take some heap dumps and see what's using the memory.  I've found this tool (https://eclipse.org/mat/) and its use of dominator trees really help with identifying which classes tie up memory.

Comment: I started playing on CodeEval with my language of choice (R), while trying to answer this guy: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86939/reducing-memory-usage-for-fizzbuzz-in-r. I am under the impression that the memory usage that is reported includes the RAM needed to run a process. Just firing up an R process takes about ~30mb so the mem usage of any R script I write will always be at least that. Maybe that in your case, a Java process requires more memory than Scala? I hope your testing will somewhat confirm my assumption. If that's how CodeEval works, that's a shame...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I conducted some tests.

There is a baseline for every type of language. I code in java and javascript. For javascript here are my test results:

[image: random challenge]

- Rev 1: Default empty boilerplate for JS with a message to standard output
- Rev 2: Same without file reading
- Rev 3: Just a message to the standard output

You can see that no matter what, there will be at least 200 ms runtime and about 5 megs of memory usage.  This baseline depends on the load of the servers as well! There was a time when codeevals was heavily overloaded, thus making impossible to run anything within the max time(10s).

Check this out, a totally different challenge than the previous:
[image: Random pic 2.]

- Rev4: My solution
- Rev5: The same code submitted again now. Scored 8000 more ranking point. :D

Conclusion: I would not worry too much about CPU and memory usage and rank. It is clearly not reliable.

Comment: Haha, I see... I also noticed that many of these sites that let you run code you wrote take significanlty more time to run Scala code than any other language I tried (the fastest being the script languages like JS or Python, which is logical). It's surprising to me because although the Scala compiler is slow, it should not be too expensive for very small code like this, without anything fancy. Anyway, my conclusion back then was the same as yours : it's not reliable. I'll take this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Your scala solution is slow, not because of "overhead on CodeEval", but because you are building an immutable `TreeSet`, adding elements to it one by one. Replacing it with something like

```
val regex = """\d+""".r // in the beginning, instead of your Pattern.compile
...
.map { line => 
    val dists = regex.findAllIn(line).map(_.toInt).toIndexedSeq.sorted
...
```

Should shave about 30-40% off your execution time.

Same approach (build a list, then sort) will, probably, help your memory utilization in "version 3" (java sets are *real* memory hogs). It is also a good idea to give your list an initial size while you are at it (otherwise, it'll grow by 50% every time it runs out of capacity, which is wasteful in both memory and performance). 600 sounds like a good number, since that's the upper bound for the number of cities from the problem description.

Now, since we know the upper boundary, an even faster and slimmer approach is to do away with lists and boxed Integeres, and just do `int dists[] = new int[600];`.

If you wanted to get really fancy, you'd also make use of the "route length" range that's mentioned in the description. For example, instead of throwing ints into an array and sorting (or keeping a treeset), make an array of 20,000 bits (or even 20K bytes for speed), and set those that you see in input as you read it ... That would be both faster and more memory efficient than any of your solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the set is actually mutable, that's true that I did not include my imports. Thus, I used it thinking that I was storing at the same time of sorting my data, in `nlog(n)` time complexity. I will try your version but I don't expect it yo give different results. As for the rest of your ideas, there are definitly things that could reduce the amount of memory used but that does not explain why there is a difference between version 3 and version 1, which main difference is the use of regexes

Comment: Ok, mutable set is better, but it is still inferior to accumulating data first, and then sorting. Both are O(nlog(n)), but the the constants are significantly different. TreeSet may be a good choice, when there is a need to maintain data in order *while it is coming in*. In this case, it will definitely be faster to just read once, and then sort. Re. version 1 vs. 3, the difference is not in regex. V1 isn't using `StringBuilder`, which does get pretty huge. I think, if you get rid of `TreeSet` in your V3, you'll beat V1's footprint easily event with `StringBuilder` intact.

Comment: I used a `LinkedList` instead of the set. It ran using comparable time and memory (a bit slower and more memory but it is likely to be due to the input data size, which varies slightly). I really think CodeEval memory test is broken since `LinkedList` introduces a memory overhead smaller than `TreeSet`, doesn't it ?.

Comment: LinkedList is terrible for sorting. Use `new ArrayList(600)`. LinkedList overhead is indeed smaller than `TreeSet` but not by much (because of the links). But I hear you about the memory stats. Their measurement can't really be very accurate because gc is impossible to predict.

Comment: `LinkedList` is good for appending at the end, and I `Collections.sort` first fills an array with its values to get fast random access. From the javadoc : `This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array.` `This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place`

Comment: Yes, `Collections.sort` will copy to array, but `ArrayList.sort` sorts in place, which is faster and needs less memory. And if you allocate it with enough initial capacity, appending is actually faster than with `LinkedList`

Comment: Ok thanks for your time. I upvote you for the good advices but I don't accept your answer as it does not explain the difference between the code. Nevertheless, I don't think it is possible to answer since the stats seem biased. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving this question and figured that you don't need the names of the cities, just the distances in a sorted array.

It has much better runtime of 738ms, and memory of 4513792 with this.

Although this may not help improve your piece of code, it seems like a better way to approach the question. Any suggestions to improve the code further are welcome.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();

        String out = new Main().getDistances(line); 

        System.out.println(out);
    }
}

public String getDistances(String s){

    //split the string
    String[] arr = s.split(";");

    //create an array to hold the distances as integers
    int[] distances = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         //find the index of , - get the characters after that - convert to integer - add to distances array
        distances[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i].substring(arr[i].lastIndexOf(",")+1));    
    }

    //sort the array
    Arrays.sort(distances);

    String output = "";
    output += distances[0]; //append the distance to the closest city to the string

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){

        //get distance between current element(city) and next
        int distance_between = distances[i+1] - distances[i];

        //append the distance to the string
        output += "," + distance_between;
    }


    return output;   
 }
 }
```

Comment: I haven't looked your code in depth, but if you read mine, I have never stored the name of the cities

Comment: You create a new `Main` for every iteration whereas your class is stateless : you could just use the same instance all the time or even better in this case, use a `static` method instead. You don't need a class here, there is no concept to model

Comment: Finally, you concatenate strings using `+=`, which can be extremely expensive for large strings. Use a `StringBuilder` instead